# Connecting to MSSQL Server from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, docker, sqlsrv

I've followed the guides at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15 and PHP is finding the drivers / server but now I'm getting an authentication error.

Verified the server is configured for "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" and allows remote connections to the server.

In order to get this error, I believe that means the code is at least connecting and attempting to authenticate with the server (changing the server to some nonsense server name/location produces a timeout error) - fairly certain that eliminates any problems that would come before the authentication step.

Still, I'm getting an error as follows...

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'username'. in /var/www/html/connect.php:10
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 /var/www/html/connect.php(10): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=S...', 'username', 'password')
>   #1 {main}root@containerIdGoesHere:/var/www/html

```
<?php

$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';

try {
     $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=SomeServer,1433;Database=SomeDb", $user, $pass);
     $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'See error log';
    $elog = fopen('errorlog.txt', 'w') or die("Couldn't open file");
    fwrite($elog, $e);
    fclose($elog);
}
```

**Note: I've removed any sensitive info from my code... so the username and pw I'm using are not 'username' and 'password' & not related to the issue.**

Comment: It appears that your script is connecting to the database as it is throwing an error for invalid credentials rather than a connectivity error. In your error the username is 'username' in which it is attempting to connect to, is this correct or have you replaced this to hide the real username?

Comment: I edited my real username and replaced with fake values

Comment: Sorry I deleted my original comment as you are actually connecting to the server, it is your credentials you are providing which is the issue

Comment: Okay, try using a different set of credentials possibly?

Comment: Tried that also :(

Comment: shouldn't be SomeServer:1433 (replace , with : ) ?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte No the comma is actually correct syntax in this case. Tried it with : just for the heck of it but it just times out since it can't locate the server anymore.

Comment: Did you try logging in with the same credentials using a sql tool like management studio?

Answer (score 1):

I've got this working on my production environment:

```
    $db = "DatabaseName";
    $password = "Password";
    $server = "TheSQLServer";
    $user = "username";
    $link = new PDO(
        "sqlsrv:Server=" . $server . 
        ";Database=" . $db, 
        $user, 
        $password
    );  

    return $link;
```

I also had to manually get into the DB and allow the previously created user to have the proper rights into it (DB->Security->Users), you can check that out aswell. Let me know how it goes.